# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'

Tags: android-studio

I have been getting this error for two days now and been busting my head against the wall:-

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\DEL\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\19.1.0\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

I have updated everything "updateable" but this is still bugging me.I have updated to android 2.1.2 and I am in windows 7. I am trying to build a blank activity with a fragment and I have written no code as of yet but the project just won't build

Here is the android manifest file:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.del.sunshine_testapp_vr1">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here is the gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.del.sunshine_testapp_vr1"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0-beta1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0-beta1'
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `build.gradle` file shows `buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"` and it is old. You should change this to latest version of `buildToolVersion` that you have in your sdk. So, now go to **C:\Users\DEL\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\** directory and find out latest version of build tool after that in your `build.gradle` file change `buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"` to that version. Now choose `Tools -> Android -> Sync with Gradle dependency`. Hope this might helpful for you.

Comment: I figured that out like about 5 hours ago but thank you anyways

Answer (score 1):

Remove `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0-beta1'`

`appcompat-v7:24.0.0-beta1`

not working with 
`buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"`

Answer (score 0):

It was throwing me the error as well when I was trying to run a flutter app. So I considered that [Shashanth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38283671/7020494) answer was correct and I ended up adding a virtual device with a newer version (Android API 28) and editing the build.gradle to match the version (28) that I just installed and it did the trick. I am not sure if it is 100% correct, since you need to add the support to the API on each machine that you run the app but at least it solves the issue.